# Character encoding in NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am working on an iOS application and I have a basic problem. I have spent many hours to resolve it but I haven't had any success.

I have some JSON like this : `{"htmlCode":"<thead><tr><td class=/"/"><p>Protected.....`

```
    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc]init]autorelease];
    NSDictionary *results = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonTableData];

    NSLog(@" result %@",results);
    result (null)
```

My problem is the :`/"/"` - how I can replace it with `\"\"`?

i would like to do something like this :

```
jsonTableData = [jsonTableData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"/"" withString:@"\"\""];
```

Comment: @Clafou, I think the (first) "charactére" misspelling was intentionally flamboyant. ;) Though with the other "Franglish" spelling mistakes, perhaps not

Comment: Please avoid using Franglish. We all aimons le French, but the langue officielle de StackOverflow is English.

Comment: I regret editing out "Caractère encoding" now, it was pretty flamboyant, now that you say it!

Comment: @Mouh Ali, sorry if it's not helpful, but my guess is that the JSON string is invalid. Rather than try to programmatically fix it on the consumer side, do you have control over how it is produced so that the escaped quotes are valid in the first place?

Comment: i am sorry of my english, but i am doing the maximum.

Comment: @ Clafou, yes i know tha the JSOn is not Valid, but for the first i would like just to correct it programmatically and later i wil check the source of the json. thanks

Comment: The slashes (/) aren't actually part of the string. They are escape characters used to stop the string terminating early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace characters in string like this!

```
NSString *str = @"<thead><tr><td class=/\"/\"><p>Protected";

NSLog(@"%@", str);

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"\\"];

NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: i am donig like this but it's not working,    jsonTableData = [jsonTableData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"/"" withString:@"\"\""];