# NSString replacing character method

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Character encoding in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515375/character-encoding-in-nsstring)

How i can replace : `/"/"` with : `\"\"` by using the `NSSTring` method :`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

i am doing like this, but it's not working :

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"/"" withString:@"\"\""];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want:
    `myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/"/"" withString:@"\\\"\\\""];`

\ is a special character which says: Careful, don't interpret next characters as you always do.
Example: Changing line in a NSString is done withe \n. In others words, do not interpret this "n" like a simple "n". I want a change of line.