# Add double quotes to NSString that is used to fetch data from database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a string like this `nsstring *mystring=@"vikas";` now i want to add this `"` so the new string would be `"vikas"`

any way to do this?

I want to perform some query like :-

```
NSString *myQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:
                  @"select * from questiontable where order = %d",ordernumber];
```

where i want to add double quotes on order like :- "order"

Comment: If this is for a sqlite3 query then don't do it this way. You should write your query with a question mark ? and use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` to add the value. This takes care of quoting and properly escaping the value. Never use string formats to create SQL queries.

Comment: rmaddy how to make that query in ? mark please help me

Answer (score 1):

You should be writing query in NSString in format:

```
NSString *myQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:
              @"select * from questiontable where \"order\" = %d",ordernumber];
```

It must work fine.

Comment: Quick explaination I made about the backslash : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515852/nsstring-replacing-caracter-methode/13515968#13515968

Answer (score 0):

Trace! You can follow the Pratyusha's approach. And, also if you use single quote than also I think your query will be executed. Have you tried that means put your vikas in like that manner- 'vikas', or in the case of assigning the same to NSString like that:-

```
NSString *mySingleQuotedString = @"'vikas'";
```

I hope, it'll also worked. Please try it. :)